# How to display my divs in the correct order in the browser?

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zz16806e/

Barebone fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zz16806e/1/

Partial HTML:

```
<div class="content setCenter">
    <div class="pageContent">
        <div id="header hidOverflow brClear">
```

How can I modify the CSS so the `body` stays under the `header` and the `footer` is under the `body`.

Currently, all of them stuck at the top.

Comment: It is probably something to do with your CSS from other parts of the page. You've a lot of CSS there and you seem to be missing a lot of HTML, clear it up and ask for help then.

Not many people will want to sift through all that.

Comment: @walther Please remove the duplicate. I have updated the question.

Comment: I've updated your title to make it (hopefully) a little bit more clear. If I still don't get what you're trying to do, feel free to change it.

Comment: @walther Yes much better... :). Btw I update the barebone fiddle but for some reason the `height` isn't even being recognized.

Comment: I changed to class and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/zz16806e/2/. I wonder why the ID wasn't working :/

Comment: AFAIK, you can't set ID to multiple values, that's why :) That's probably the reason behind your problems. You do that all over the place.

Comment: Oh DAMN!!! I didn't realize it was an ID and I had the same on all of them `brClear` silly ME!!! :)

Comment: My web developer mind was blank!!!!! Jeez. Thanks! for knocking some sense into me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id="header hidOverflow brClear"`
is the problematic piece of code. You can't set ID to multiple values. There's only one ID. If you need to assign multiple values so you can reference it from your css, you have to use `class = "... ... "` instead. That probably caused all your problems, because you do that all over the place.

Comment: can you pelase help with something which is related to the issue above?

Comment: Does the problem still persist after you've changed it all to classes? Fiddle looks still the same, so can't tell...

Comment: Nevermind. It looks good. Thanks. I will accept your answer. :)